# @font-face for IE8 weird behaviour

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

I use fontsquirrel's CSS for @font-face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'pf_agora_serif_promedium';
    src: url('pfagoraserifpro-medium-webfont.eot');
    src: url('pfagoraserifpro-medium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('pfagoraserifpro-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('pfagoraserifpro-medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('pfagoraserifpro-medium-webfont.svg#pf_agora_serif_promedium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It works correctly in all browsers if 
    a)I use fonts that fontsquirrel generated. 
    b)I don't use cyrilic charset or another characters that could be on my font file but fontsquirrel does not converting at all (like russian letters ЯЩЮИГЛЬЦЫЧ)

So, when I changed my font files on my directory to another (which contain russian letters) IE9 and lesser don't show my font at all, even if I use only latin charset, but it works correctly (with latin and cyrilic charset) in normal browsers. So what's wrong. Does the problem inside of font files? And if not, why font-face don't working when I changing only font files?

p.s. I'd tried to use another CSS for font-face but they didn't work at my web-site.

Comment: You are not describing what actual fonts you are using, but presumably something is wrong with some of them, or with the way you are using them. But in any case, when using FontSquirrel, you should select the “Expert” option in order to cover Cyrillic letters – the default is “Basic Subsetting”, which means “Western Languages” only. If problems remain, please describe exactly what happens, in a reproducable way (identifying the fonts used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think fonts path is not giving you,

Please check `fonts local path`, may i sure working in all browser this `@font-face` kit,

`EOT` fortmat for ie8 and ie 9

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "pf_agora_serif_promedium";
  src: url("yourlocalpath/pfagoraserifpro-medium-webfont.eot");
  src: local("☺"),
  url("yourlocalpath/pfagoraserifpro-medium-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
  url("yourlocalpath/pfagoraserifpro-medium-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("yourlocalpath/pfagoraserifpro-medium-webfont.svg#LucidaFax-bold") format("svg");
  }
```